# Binary files in C++

Tags: c++, file, qt, binary

I want to store data from desired byte upto another desired byte of the file opened in binary mode in to another file. Lets say file pointer is at byte# 10, now i want to read data from byte # 11 to byte # 30. I know i have to use fread() function but don't know how to tell this function to read from desired location upto another desired location. I am a beginner so bear answering this question.

I know fread() is C function, I want C++ equivalent functions for doing this work. A link or suggestion of book for learning file handling will be great!

Thanks alot for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You have to seek:

```
std::ifstream infile("source.bin", std::ios::binary);

infile.seekg(10, std::ios::beg);  // seek to 10 bytes from the beginning

char buf[20];

if (!infile.read(buf, 20)) { /* error */ }

// now your data is in buf
```

The stdio interface is is similar, but since this is C++, we prefer the iostreams one. You must never, ever use I/O operations without checking their return value, and in iostreams this is fairly easy. With `fread` you have to be careful to interpret the return value correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the prototype for fread is :

```
size_t fread ( void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE * stream );
```

And fseek is:

```
int fseek ( FILE * stream, long int offset, int origin );
```

If you want to get to byte #11, you can do:

```
fseek(file, 11, SEEK_SET) // this means: go 11 bytes from the start position.
```

or, since you're already at byte 10, you can do:

```
fseek(file, 1, SEEK_CUR)  // this means: go 1 byte beyond current position.
```

Then, to read up to byte 30 from byte 11, you need to read 19 bytes (30 - 11), so you do:

```
fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 19, file).
```

Comment: I'm very tempted to say that using `fread` without examining its return value is a programming error.